# How to exclude joined table data from query results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Suppose I have the following query,

```php
$results = Listing::select('listings.id', 'listings.slug', 'page_contents.html_title AS name')
    ->join('page_contents', function ($join) {
        $join->on('page_contents.subject_id', '=', 'listings.id')
            ->where('page_contents.subject_type', '=', 'App\Listing');
    })
    ->get();
```

`$results` will include the specified select columns (which is all I need), but also, all data for `page_contents`,

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "slug": "omnis-et-harum-atque",
    "name": "Omnis et harum atque",
    "page_content": {
         "id": 3,
         "subject_type": "App\\Listing",
         "subject_id": 3,
         "html_title": "Omnis et harum atque",
         "meta_title": "Omnis et harum atque",
         ... and a load more stuff I don't want,
         "created_at": "2019-05-23 09:16:37",
         "updated_at": "2019-05-23 09:16:37"
    }
}
```

How do I remove `page_content` from the returned data. The data is being returned for an API and so the `page_data` info is way over the top.

Laravel 5.8

Cheers

Comment: You should see what sql is being generated by appending `})->toSql();` and then `dd($results);`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick would do:
Inside your model Listing:
use attribute $hidden = ['pageContent or whatever the name of your relation to table is'];
While serializing, this relation will be hidden by default, You would have to make it visible whenever you want.

Comment: Not quite what I needed but got me on the right path. It's a one off case where I want the extra data excluded, so excluding it by default didn't make sense. I found the method to exclude it from the items in the collection - `makeHidden()`. Cheers.

Comment: yeah, that could do the trick as well. It's similar to makeVisible. Either way will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting after you join and use simple join statement maybe?:

```
$results = Listing::join('page_contents','page_contents.subject_id', '=', 'listings.id')
            ->where('page_contents.subject_type', '=', 'App\Listing')
            ->select('listings.id', 'listings.slug', 'page_contents.html_title AS name')
            ->get();
```

PS. I don't know how your query is even returning the result without any get() or first() call or maybe you didn't provide the full query.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: I can't use a smiple join as it's a polymorphic relationship and adding the select after the join makes no difference. Also, I'd left out `->get()`, as I was removing bits of code that weren't relevant and got carried away - now updated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this answer here as it's how I've solved the problem, I feel like there's a better way hidden somewhere though. The solution appears to rely on the join being a defined relationship on the model. It would be nice to be able to exclude the data at the query level.

To exclude data from the items in a collection, `makeHidden()` can be used.

```php
$results = Listing::select('listings.id', 'listings.slug', 'page_contents.html_title AS name')
    ->join('page_contents', function ($join) {
        $join->on('page_contents.subject_id', '=', 'listings.id')
            ->where('page_contents.subject_type', '=', 'App\Listing');
    })
    ->get();

$results->makeHidden('pageContent');
```

If using `->paginate($size)` instead of `->get()`,

```php
$results->getCollection()->makeHidden('pageContent');
```

Hope that helps someone...